# Angular cors error while accessing google auth from express js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors, passport-google-oauth2

Error: redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/auth/google') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

even though i am using cors module in server i am getting this error.

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Tried this one also instead of cors

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log("entered cors")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET , PUT , POST , DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-requested-with");
    next();
})
```

my service code in angular

When i click login with google button this servicemethod will get executed

```
addGoogleUser():Observable<any>{
  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  headers.set('content-type','application/json')
  return this.http.get("http://localhost:5000/auth/google",{headers:headers});
}
```

Comment: You don’t have to set those headers on the angular side.. that might actually cause CORS issues..

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: removing headers in angular did'nt solve either

Answer (score -1):

**Try below -**

```
app.get('/auth/google', cors(), (req, res) => {
        // your get code
 });
```

Comment: I tried but same error again

Comment: without having full code is difficult to see the issue. Could you upload your code to stackblitz and share ?

Comment: do i need to upload the whole project or server  file and angular service is fine?

Comment: https://github.com/kowsikgelli/mean_auth

Comment: check server.js and  angular-frontend/src/app/services/auth.service.ts

Comment: in auth.service.ts check addGoogleUser function

Answer (score -1):

In your express service:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
```

Or

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
```

And make sure you call `app.use((req, res, next) => {}` before calling your other routes.

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: it is working when is paste the link directly in browser ihttp://localhost:5000/auth/google  can access the google account info  it is not working from angular. blocking due to cors policy

Comment: Ok also make sure your request and endpoint matches what your api expects. Sometimes that might be an issue and your server doesn't know how to respond to your request.